# How to define multiple classes at the same time using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have two classes that depend on each other in Java.

Example:

```java
public class A {
    public B b;
}
```

```java
public class B{
    public A a;
}
```

Now, I must define these two classes in JNI using `env->DefineClass`. Example:

```cpp
static const unsigned char A_bytes[] = { /* ... */ };
static const unsigned char B_bytes[] = { /* ... */ };

// later in the code
app->env->DefineClass(nullptr, classLoader, (const jbyte*) A_bytes, (jsize) sizeof(A_bytes));
app->env->DefineClass(nullptr, classLoader, (const jbyte*) B_bytes, (jsize) sizeof(B_bytes));
```

This gives me the error:

```
Exception loading class:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (path of B)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find class (path of B)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Looks like you can't. You would have to be the Java compiler for that.